# Android broadcast receiver for media controls stops working after app is closed

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, media, receiver

So I've been trying to build a music player app and despite visiting all pages on stackoverflow I'm still stuck on one issue. The code works fine for the most part, but when I press the back button to close the app the action buttons stop working, even though they work fine when I press the home button. I think the broadcast receiver is getting unregistered when the app is closed even though I don't want it to. Here is the code:

```
public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getExtras().getString("actionname");
        Helper.makeToast(context, action);

        switch (action) {
            case CreateNotification.ACTION_PREVIUOS:
//play previous
            case CreateNotification.ACTION_PLAY:

                if (isPlaying) {
                    //pause
                } else {
                   // play
                }


                break;
            case CreateNotification.ACTION_NEXT:
               //play next
        }
    }
};
```

This is the onresume method on main activity

```
 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TRACKS_TRACKS"));
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), OnClearFromRecentService.class));
    }

}
```

This is the Service

```
public class OnClearFromRecentService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver .services.OnClearFromRecentService" />
```

So my questions are: Is the broadcastreceiver automatically unregistered when I close the app? If so, how do I prevent this? How do I keep the broadcast receiver working when I close the app?

Answer (score 0):

This type of receivers unregister automatically when you close your app. This is right. However you have to unregister from your receiver in onStop(). Because if you don't do this you are going to get LeakIntentMemory error message in your LogCat but your app don't crashes. You can check it from your logcat. I think that if you want to receive something when your app closed, you have to declare your receiver in AndroidManifest with an action name.

```
 <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="first.custom.action"> </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Still the same result. When the action buttons are clicked while the app is running, it works fine. But as soon as I click the back button to close the app, the action buttons stop working.